# Fastest method to update all list entries with union of all intersecting entries

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, performance, intersection

I am looking for a fast method to traverse a list of sets, and to expand each set by finding its union with any other element of the list with which it shares at least one element.

For example, suppose that I have four rows of data, where each row corresponds to a set of unique elements

```
0, 5, 101
8, 9, 19, 21
78, 79
5, 7, 63, 64
```

The first and the last rows have the intersecting element 5 and so after performing my operation I want to have the unions

```
0, 5, 7, 63, 64, 101
8, 9, 19, 21
78, 79
0, 5, 7, 63, 64, 101
```

Right now, I can nearly do this with two loops:

```
def consolidate_list(arr):
    """
    arr (list) : A list of lists, where the inner lists correspond to sets of unique integers
    """
    arr_out = list()
    for item1 in arr:
        item_additional = list() # a list containing all overlapping elements
        for item2 in arr:
            if len(np.intersect1d(item1, item2)) > 0:
                item_additional.append(np.copy(item2))
        out_val = np.unique(np.hstack([np.copy(item1)] + item_additional)) # find union of all lists

        arr_out.append(out_val)
        
return arr_out
```

The issue with this approach is that it needs to be run multiple times, until the output stops changing. Since the input might be jagged (ie, different numbers of elements per set), I can't see a way to vectorize this function.

Comment: The first idea that comes to mind: (1) Build a graph where each vertex is one of your sets, and two sets share an edge iff they have an element in common. (2) Identify the connected components of the graph. (3) Merge all sets that belong to the same connected component. You can consider using module [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html) to build the graphs and identify the connected components.

Comment: I have fixed the typo. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is about creating [disjoint sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) and so I would use union-find methods.

Now Python is not particularly known for being fast, but for the sake of showing the algorithm, here is an implementation of a `DisjointSet` class without libraries:

```
class DisjointSet:
    class Element:
        def __init__(self):
            self.parent = self
            self.rank = 0


    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = {}

    def find(self, key):
        el = self.elements.get(key, None)
        if not el:
            el = self.Element()
            self.elements[key] = el
        else: # Path splitting algorithm
            while el.parent != el:
                el, el.parent = el.parent, el.parent.parent
        return el

    def union(self, key=None, *otherkeys):
        if key is not None:
            root = self.find(key)
            for otherkey in otherkeys:
                el = self.find(otherkey)
                if el != root:
                    # Union by rank
                    if root.rank < el.rank:
                        root, el = el, root
                    el.parent = root
                    if root.rank == el.rank:
                        root.rank += 1

    def groups(self):
        result = { el: [] for el in self.elements.values() 
                          if el.parent == el }
        for key in self.elements:
            result[self.find(key)].append(key)
        return result
```

Here is how you could use it for this particular problem:

```
def solve(lists):
    disjoint = DisjointSet()
    for lst in lists:
        disjoint.union(*lst)
            
    groups = disjoint.groups()
    return [lst and groups[disjoint.find(lst[0])] for lst in lists]
```

Example call:

```
data = [
    [0, 5, 101],
    [8, 9, 19, 21],
    [],
    [78, 79],
    [5, 7, 63, 64]
]
result = solve(data)
```

The result will be:

```
[[0, 5, 101, 7, 63, 64], [8, 9, 19, 21], [], [78, 79], [0, 5, 101, 7, 63, 64]]
```

Note that I added an empty list in the input list, so to illustrate that this boundary case remains unaltered.

NB: There are libraries out there that provide union-find/disjoint set functionality, each with a slightly different API, but I suppose that using one of those can give a better performance.

Comment: I think better wikipedia link is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure, which is actually link from the given wiki page anyway.

Comment: OP's code's output for input `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]` is `[array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([2, 3, 4])]`. Your code's output for the same input is `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`. I don't know which is correct. Just FYI.

Comment: @גלעד ברקן, the last paragraph of the question explains this (intermediate) result that the Asker's code produces (it must be run multiple times).

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining. The outputs become the same when rerun.

Comment: @גלעדברקן that's right, I will edit the question to make that point clearer. So far this looks incredible (and much more efficient than my double loop approach). Thank you for this incredible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by?:

```
from itertools import combinations
l1 = [0, 5, 7, 63, 64, 101]
l2 = [8, 9, 19]
l3 = [78, 79]
l4 = [5, 4, 34]
print([v for x, y in combinations([l1, l2, l3, l4], 2) for v in {*x} & {*y}])
```

Output:

```
[5]
```

Comment: your code "reinvent" `set.intersection` :-)

Comment: @balderman Well this wouldn't work with a regular intersection

Comment: Anyway the OP is looking for something different.  " I am interesting in traversing a list of sets, for each entry finding all elements that intersect with that entry, and then replace that entry with the union of all elements that intersected"